# Validate submitHandler on id javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

How can I set my submitHandler on an id. I want to be able to submit my handler for validation on an id. Here is the code:

```
$("#validate").validate({
    rules: {
        "name-contact": {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        "name-contact": {
            required: "Please, enter a name"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function () { 
        return false; 
    }   
});
```

I want to change my submitHander to be able to accept id so that I submit to the validation on id. Here is the code is not working but it gives an example of what I am talking about:

```
    $("#validate").submitHandler: function () { 
        return false; 
    }
```

That code is not working, from what I can see it does not set because of the comas. How can I set my submitHandler on id?

Comment: What do you mean "set your submitHandler on an id." Do you mean for a particular form?

Comment: yea for a particular form

Answer (score 0):

The `submitHandler` is an option of the jQuery Validate plugin.   It's a *callback function* that fires whenever you click submit AND then only if the *entire* form passes validation.   So your question really makes no sense in this context.

Your code:

```
$("#validate").submitHandler: function () { 
    return false; 
}
```

You cannot just attach `submitHandler` to a jQuery selector like that.   It goes *inside* of the `.validate()` method, which is attached to your form selector, like this...

```
$("#validate").validate({
    // rules & options, 
    submitHandler: function(form) {
       // your custom submit handler function
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/VRLPM/**

Please show the HTML markup, explain better what you're really trying to do and why the normal usage of the plugin does not meet your needs.